# Some help to understand method of bijection using counting

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

I am trying to make sense of the argument that $$| \mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N}|=|\mathbb{N}|$$

via finding a bijection ( not using Cantor-Bernstein).

The method I want to use is to do by considering the list of pairs as

$$(0,0) (0,1) (0,2) (0,3) (0,4)...$$ 
$$(1,0) (1,1) (1,2)  (1,3)  (1,4)...$$
$$(2,0) (2,1) (2,2) (2,3) (2,4)...$$

and counting as

$\begin{matrix} 0 & 1 & 3 & 6 & 10.. \\ 2 & 4 & 7 & 11... \\ 5 & 8 & 12 & 17.. \\ 9 & 13 & 18.. \end{matrix}$

Ie a way to map from each pair to a single natural number.

My thoughts:

I have noticed a few things, first off if we order the points as $(m,n)$ and the diagonal as k beginning with the 0th diagonal, we have that $m+n=k$

Also, I see that it appears as if $f(0,n)-f(0,n-1)=n$ , but I am not sure how I can prove it is always true. For example, $f(0,3)-f(0,2)=6-3=3$, $f(0,4)-f(0,3)=10-6=4$ etc. So f(0,n)=f(0,n-1)+n. but $f(0,n-1)=f(0,n-2)+(n-1)$

so it appears that $$f(0,n)=n+(n-1)+...+1+0=\frac{n(n+1)}{2}$$

I also notice that the kth diagonal has $k+1$ points.

I am not sure how I can tie it together or if it is correct approach. I am not sure how to make it formal either. Any help is appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're almost there.

You've seen that you need to define $f(0,n) = \frac{n(n+1)}{2}$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$. Now notice that
$$f(k,n-k) = \frac{n(n+1)}{2}+k$$
for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$ and all $k \le n$.

Replacing $n-k$ by $\ell$, we obtain
$$f(k,\ell) = \frac{(k+\ell)(k+\ell+1)}{2} + k$$
for all $(k,\ell) \in \mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N}$.

You can now check that this defines a bijection.

---

Another possible bijection uses prime factorisation. Define $g : \mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N}$ by $g(k,\ell) = 2^k(2\ell+1)-1$ for all $(k,\ell) \in \mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N}$ and check the details.